# npm install geckodriver fails because of file not found [WSL]

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, geckodriver

In the context of building a project with a dependency on selenium-cucumber-js, I'm trying to install geckodriver in the following setup:

- OS: WSL Ubuntu 16.04
- Node: 8.15.0 (installed from nvm)
- NPM: 5.10.0 (installed from nvm)

When I execute `npm install geckodriver`, I get the following error message:

```
npm ERR! path /home/username/myfolder/node_modules/geckodriver/bin/geckodriver
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/home/username/myfolder/node_modules/geckodriver/bin/geckodriver'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/username/.npm/_logs/2019-02-16T07_38_34_159Z-debug.log
```

There is no more information that I can find in the log.
I can successfully install geckodriver with webdriver-manager, but it doesn't meet the selenium-cucumber-js dependency in the package.json.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: seems like a version-wide issue. The same issue was also reported by other people on the github tracker. https://github.com/vladikoff/node-geckodriver/issues/59

`npm install geckodriver@1.14` works just fine.